# CLion (C++) : unable to open image using SFML

Tags: macos, clion

I just started using CLion to build my projects and tried to launch one of my previous ones to test. Compiler doesn't return any errors, but when I try to run the executable it says `unable to open "img.png"` but it worked fine when i compiled it in terminal and launched.

Comment: Maybe CLion doesn't copy the image to the build directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in case anyone faces the same problem. CLion searches for resources in debug/release folder by default. Changing the default directory or writing `"../img.png"` instead of `"img.png"` solves the issue.